# Command for front side bus speed of the system in Linux

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find virtual memory size and cache size of a linux system?](https://superuser.com/questions/48505/how-to-find-virtual-memory-size-and-cache-size-of-a-linux-system)

I have Linux debian version2.6.18 which does not have lshw/dmidecode command, dmesg does not give external clock info. is there any other command?

Answer (score 2):

All of the information that the OS gets by default is in `/proc/cpuinfo`, but I doubt you'll find the FSB.  You'd be better off rebooting and looking in BIOS.  The OS pretty much doesn't care about FSB speeds.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Most computers will display your front side bus (fsb) speed during boot up