# Where is this file system, /cpu/pal on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, cache

while reading some answers here on SU, I see that [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/48505/how-to-find-virtual-memory-size-and-cache-size-of-a-linux-system/244490#244490) mentions of using the below command

```
cat /proc/pal/cpu0/cache_info
```

on a Linux system(no distribution mentioned there in the answer) to get detailed information about the cache memory on the system, such as below.

But I do not have this file system /cpu/pal/ on my Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit system? Any pointers where & how can I get such detailed information cache on Ubuntu?

```
Cache levels  : 3
Unique caches : 5

Data Cache level 1:
        Size           : 16384 bytes
        Attributes     : WriteThrough
        Associativity  : 4
        Line size      : 64 bytes
        Stride         : 128 bytes
        Store latency  : 0 cycle(s)
        Load latency   : 1 cycle(s)
        Store hints    :
        Load hints     : [Temporal, level 1]
        Alias boundary : 4096 byte(s)
        Tag LSB        : 12
        Tag MSB        : 49
Instruction Cache level 1:
        Size           : 16384 bytes
        Attributes     :
        Associativity  : 4
        Line size      : 64 bytes
        Stride         : 128 bytes
        Store latency  : N/A
        Load latency   : 1 cycle(s)
        Store hints    :
        Load hints     : [Temporal, level 1]
        Alias boundary : 4096 byte(s)
        Tag LSB        : 12
        Tag MSB        : 49
Data Cache level 2:
        Size           : 262144 bytes
        Attributes     : WriteBack
        Associativity  : 8
        Line size      : 128 bytes
        Stride         : 128 bytes
        Store latency  : 7 cycle(s)
        Load latency   : 5 cycle(s)
        Store hints    : [Temporal, level 1][Non-temporal, all levels]
        Load hints     : [Temporal, level 1][Non-temporal, level 1][Non-temporal, all levels]
        Alias boundary : 4096 byte(s)
        Tag LSB        : 15
        Tag MSB        : 49
Instruction Cache level 2:
        Size           : 524288 bytes
        Attributes     :
        Associativity  : 8
        Line size      : 128 bytes
        Stride         : 128 bytes
        Store latency  : N/A
        Load latency   : 7 cycle(s)
        Store hints    :
        Load hints     : [Temporal, level 1][Non-temporal, level 1][Non-temporal, all levels]
        Alias boundary : 4096 byte(s)
        Tag LSB        : 16
        Tag MSB        : 49
Data/Instruction Cache level 3:
        Size           : 4194304 bytes
        Attributes     : Unified WriteBack
        Associativity  : 8
        Line size      : 128 bytes
        Stride         : 128 bytes
        Store latency  : 7 cycle(s)
        Load latency   : 14 cycle(s)
        Store hints    : [Temporal, level 1]
        Load hints     : [Temporal, level 1][Non-temporal, level 1]
        Alias boundary : 4096 byte(s)
        Tag LSB        : 19
        Tag MSB        : 49
```

Comment: PAL stands for Processor Abstraction Layer and apparantly is a feature of Itanium (IA-64) CPUs.